# Alternative form for U(2) matrix

Tags: matrices

Do you know how to demonstrate the alternative form that there is in “elementary constructions”?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "general expression" is
$$U = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -e^{i\phi}b^*&e^{i\phi}a^*\end{pmatrix}$$
where $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ and $\det(U) = e^{i\phi}$. The alternative form you mentioned is
$$U = e^{i\phi/2}\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\phi_1}\cos\theta & e^{i\phi_2}\sin\theta \\ -e^{-i\phi_2}\sin\theta &e^{-i\phi_1}\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
To get this from the first form, first of all lets write $a = e^{i\phi/2}A$ and $b = e^{i\phi/2}B$. Then moving from the general expression we have
$$U = e^{i\phi/2}\begin{pmatrix} A&B\\ -B^*&A^*\end{pmatrix}$$
now write $A = r_1e^{i\phi_1}$ and $B = r_2e^{i\phi_2}$. Since $|r_1|^2 + |r_2|^2 = 1$ is the equation of the circle, there is some $\theta$ such that $r_1 = \cos\theta$ and $r_2 = \sin\theta$. So, plug in $A =  e^{i\phi_1}\cos\theta$ and $B = e^{i\phi_2}\sin\theta$ and you will have the alternative form.